# I would like to count data from HTML table availble on multiple page for specific text webdriver java

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

- I am trying Count total number of rows.
- I need to count the different type of status available (Inactive,Active,Expired & Exhausted)

  Current code is only fetching:

  - Count of rows
  - Text of Status and Name but I need only count written next to Status type.
  - It only fetch data from first page. Pages are populated based on the number transactions.

  following is the code written:

  ```
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

  public class counting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      String Status="Inactive";
      //String NextPage="Inactive";
      WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      driver.navigate().to("http://Testsite/web");
      driver.findElement(By.id("UserEntry")).sendKeys("00"); 

        //Type Last Name

      driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("Test");

         // Click on Submit

      driver.findElement(By.id("LoginButton")).click();

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accounts"));

      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Accounts")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/div[3]/div/div[2]/table /tbody/tr/td[1]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();

      List<WebElement> Account =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='MainPlaceholder_AccountList']/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
      List<WebElement> AccountStatus = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@id='MainPlaceholder_AccountList']/tbody/tr/td[5]"));
      System.out.println("Total Account- "+Account.size());
      System.out.println("Total Status- "+AccountStatus.size());
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't fully formatted properly. I have used Appium (so it is selenium backend) for mobile tests and I am going to assume you could try to create a table that reaches to a certain point, and then rows that are composed of a certain className (or in your case I suppose a id value).

Ex:

```
table = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[2]/UIATableView[1]"));
rows = table.findElementsByClassName("UIATableCell");
```

The driver being a IOSDriver. Now this is how I locate certain elements for the iOS tests. But again, I am going to assume the logic is the same. Once you locate what you need, just populate your array with the objects.

Once you populate your array you could probably parse it to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am trying fetch data from table, populated on different page for specific text (available in different rows)

Comment: I hope the code is now fully visible and aligned.Thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, your code is fully visible now. Now, I hope I can help here, did you try perhaps parsing the html code that corresponds to each new page (I am going to assume that they are different for each new table) and then trying to fetch the day from the code's specific handles?

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0;i<AccountStatus.size();i++){
                if(AccountStatus.get(i).getText().equals(Status))
                System.out.println(Account.get(i).getText()+" ---    "+AccountStatus.get(i).getText());

        }

    }

}


    HTML COde:

   <table id="MainPlaceholder_AccountList" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10"    border="1" style="background-color:#888888;width:100%;font-size: 75%; padding: 5px;" rules="all">
    <tbody>
    <tr align="center" style="color:White;background-color:#232356;">
    <th scope="col">Account Name</th>
    <th scope="col">Number</th>
  <th scope="col">Program</th>
  <th scope="col">Site</th>
  <th scope="col">Status</th>
  <th scope="col">Edit</th>
  <th scope="col">Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background-color:White;">
   <td class="capText" style="width:220px;">Last, First</td>
     <td class="padIt" align="center" style="width:60px;">4563201</td>
  <td class="capText" style="width:150px;"> </td>
  <td class="padIt" style="width:115px;">local</td>
  <td class="padIt" style="width:90px;">Active</td>
  <td style="width:75px;">
  <td style="width:75px;">
  <td style="width:75px;">
   <input id="MainPlaceholder_AccountList_EditAccount_0" type="submit"   style="width:75px;" eid="550" value="Edit..." name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$AccountList$ctl02$EditAccount">
</td>
  <td style="width:75px;">
 <input id="MainPlaceholder_AccountList_DeleteAccount_0" type="submit" style="width:75px;" eid="550" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the selected account?');" value="Delete" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$AccountList$ctl02$DeleteAccount">
</td>

  td style="text-align: center">
    <span id="MainPlaceholder_PageLabel" style="margin-right: 5px;">Page:</span>
  <input id="MainPlaceholder_CurrentPage" type="text" style="width:40px;text-align: right" onclick="javascript:this.value="";" title="Type in a page number, then press the Enter key to go directly to that page." maxlength="5" value="1" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$CurrentPage">
  <span id="MainPlaceholder_OfLabel" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">of</span>
  <span id="MainPlaceholder_TotalPages" style="margin-right: 5px;">21</span>
    <input id="MainPlaceholder_LastButton" type="submit" style="height:24px;width:90px;" value="▼▼ Last" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$LastButton">
  <input id="MainPlaceholder_NextButton" type="submit" style="height:24px;width:90px;" value="▼ Next" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$NextButton">
    <input id="MainPlaceholder_PreviousButton" type="submit" style="height:24px;width:90px;" value="Previous ▲" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$PreviousButton">
    <input id="MainPlaceholder_FirstButton" type="submit" style="height:24px;width:90px;" value="First ▲▲" name="ctl00$MainPlaceholder$FirstButton">
</td>
```